# How to sum a nested list in Python?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I want to sum a nested list in Python, an example is shown below:

```
[[[1,2], [3,4]], [[5,6], [7,8]]] -> [[6,8], [10,12]]
```

It should basically sum the 2 nested lists of N rows and N columns and output one list with N rows and N columns.

What I've tried to do so far is concatenate all the nested lists elements to the first list:

```
for idx in range(len(implemented_moves[0])):
    for snd_idx in range(1, len(implemented_moves)):
        implemented_moves[0][idx] +=  implemented_moves[snd_idx][idx]
```

Output [it merges rather than concat]: `[[1,2,6,8],[3,4,7,8]]`

Comment: Is the input list of unknown dimension? You’ve shown one that’s a list of list of lists, while another is a list of lists?

Comment: the input is of known dimension and always uniform. so the lists of lists size will always be the same

Comment: How do you arrive at 6 and 8 for the result? Show the math.

Comment: Remind me how you get [6,8] from [[1,2],[3,4]]

Comment: yea so in the input, the first list of lists, at index [0] is [1,2] and the second one the same is [5,6].
I basically want to add it such that its 1+5 and 2+6 => [6,8]

Comment: @Ayman.1302, what result should be for the input: `[[[1,2,3], [3,4,5]], [[5,6,7], [7,8,9]], [[10,11,12], [13,14,15]]]` ? Do you need to sum up only adjacent rows separately?

Answer (score 2):

If you have homogeneous dimensions, this is a good job for [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
import numpy as np

l = [[[1,2], [3,4]], [[5,6], [7,8]]]
out = np.array(l).sum(0).tolist()
```

With pure python, using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
l = [[[1,2], [3,4]], [[5,6], [7,8]]]
out = [[c+d for c, d in zip(a, b)] for a, b in zip(*l)]
# or
# out = [[sum(y) for y in zip(*x)]for x in zip(*l)]
```

Output:

```
[[6, 8], [10, 12]]
```

Comment: In SO, "thanks, this works" is spelled "upvote" and "accept answer" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple one:

```py
# input
arrays = [
    [
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9]
    ],
    [
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9]
    ]
]

# split into 2 separate arrays
arr1, arr2 = arrays

# don't assume these are square matrices
n, m = len(arr1), len(arr1[0])

# calculate the output
output = [[arr1[row][col] + arr2[row][col] for col in range(m)] for row in range(n)]

# print formatted output
print('\n'.join(' '.join(f'{x:2}' for x in row) for row in output))

#  2  4  6
#  8 10 12
# 14 16 18
```